# DataGridComboBoxColumn does not bind back to UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am still fairly new to WPF and MVVM.  I added a DataGridComboBoxColumn to a DataGrid.  Binding to the view object works fine.  However when I re-open the screen after saving the combobox does not display the value previously saved (basically binding from view back to UI does not work).

Below is an idea of what I am trying to do:

The below three classes are my view classes

ViewPosition is the class type of the rows in my data grid (see XAML below).  ViewPosition contains a reference to ViewPricing.
ViewPricing contains a reference to a parentSecurity (string type).
Security is a security containing a Description property.

```
public class ViewPosition : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private long _securityID;
    private long _portfolioID;
    private DateTime _positionDate;
    private ViewPricing viewPricing;

    public ViewPricing Pricing
    {
        get { return viewPricing; }
        set
        {
            viewPricing= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class ViewPricing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String parentSecurity;
    private decimal quantity;
    private decimal price;
    private decimal yield;
    private decimal spread;

    public string ParentSecurity
    {
        get { return parentSecurity; }
        set
        {
            if (parentSecurity != value)
            {
                parentSecurity  = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("parentSecurity");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Security : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my view model.  This fetches a list of all available securities.

```
public class PositionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Security> _securities;

    private List<Security> _securities;
    public List<Security> Securities
    {
    get { return _securities; }
    set
    {
        if (_securities != value)
        {
            _securities = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally here is my XAML.

1. I want the user to see the security description in the combo box.  This is why I set DisplayMemberPath="Description".
2. Upon saving I want the combo box value to be saved in Pricing.ParentSecurity.  This is why I set SelectedValueBinding and SelectedValuePath as below.

The list of securities shows correctly the combo box. The binding to the view object is working (combobox value is saved to Pricing.ParentSecurity).  The problem I am having is that the binding from view object back to UI (combo box) does not work.  If close then re-open my window then the combo box doesn't show the value (it is blank).

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Parent Security" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Pricing.ParentSecurity, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Description" DisplayMemberPath="Description"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Securities, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Securities, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
            </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Thanks for any help/suggestions you can provide!

Comment: Remove the if from your setter. Objects are always equal unless you override equals.

Comment: @Cart: Where and how is the value "saved"? What happens when you open the window?